# What are some easy to built Drupal modules to design Job portal and community site?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-templates

I want to build a Job portal where a recruiters can post jobs and seekers can apply through one click. Seeker's profile regarded as Resume. Recruiter and job seeker registration should be approved by Administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only pre-packaged Drupal job board installation profiles or scripts are D7 based at this time. Two to consider are:

- [The Recruiter Installation Profile (Free)](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter)
- [The Drupal Classifieds Bundle (Paid Theme)](https://www.themesnap.com/premium-drupal-themes/jobboard.html)

For Drupal 8, you can build this using CCK, Views, & an open source theme, although "one click" applications may require a custom module to implement.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what exactly I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: easy is nothing if you want to make something valuable. However, I can give you a little advice about the path that you could follow to get the best of Drupal for your development:

- Learn to use the **paragraphs module** first to get the structure for
  your data.
- Then learn to **manage the form display** for your structures
  so people can input your data more easily (see "manage form display"
  tab).
- Then learn to **manage different displays** to show your
  information as you want (see "manage display" tab).
- Learn **views** to
  display groups of information with different filters and criteria.

In my experience when you start with a solution that does "everything" for you at the beginning, this solution will get in your way more sooner than later.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice.